# How to get from input data while input ng-model is ngRepeat variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a edit form which is already filled with exciting data as default as follows:

```
<form>
     <div ng-repeat="x in names">
       <input type="text" ng-model="x.name"> 
       <input type="submit" ng-click="editFeed(x)" value="Edit">
     </div>
    </form>
```

and the controller

```
 $scope.names = [
        {
            name: 'jack',
        },
        {
            name: 'tom'
        },
        {
            name: 'jackson'
        }
    ]
    $scope.x= {}; 
    $scope.editFeed = function(x){
        alert($scope.x.name);
    };
```

That gives me undefined because 'x' is ng-repeat variable. If we replace 'x' with another value; exp: 't'. I would get the input form data however that is not the issue..

So, how can I get input form data if input ng-model value is ng-repeat value..?

any tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `$scope`. You are passing in `x` as an argument, so you can just use it:

```
$scope.editFeed = function(x){
    alert(x.name);
};
```